# There must be an @Id field (String, Long, or long)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I've been trying to figure out how to solved this issue:

```
There must be an @Id field (String, Long, or long)
```

Although there is a `@Id` annoation  in the class. I tried doing mvn clean, Eclipse project clean, there is no compile time errors. However when I run my application and try to persist a registered entity, I get this error.

I am using Objectify-4 and using the OfyLoader pattern.

**CODE:**

```
import java.util.List;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;

@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private List<String> strList;

    public TestEntity() {}

    public TestEntity(List<String> strList){
        this.setStrList(strList);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public List<String> getStrList() {
        return strList;
    }
    public void setStrList(List<String> strList) {
        this.strList = strList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question with the entity code, I actually created a new TestEntity just to test things out, still having the same issue.

Comment: I guess you need to import the `@Id` from somewhere else.

Comment: Any chance you have an old (objectify3) jar still on the classpath?  There does not appear to be anything wrong with your code, assuming you call `register(TestEntity.class)`. You could try posting the complete stacktrace of the error if you still want help.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure on objectify 4 is on your classpath and the only id import is :

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly package then run your project. Because if you jetty run, for example, run operation cannot see annotations